# Is this a correct usage of "scratching the surface"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

Scratching the surface of the universe through science and technology.

To my ear it sounds as if something is wrong with this sentence. Is this a correct sentence from grammatical point-of-view? More importantly, does it make sense?

Comment: It's not a sentence.  It would be a sentence if it began "We are only . . ."

Comment: @Xanne It is a nominal sentence. http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-nominal-sentence.htm

Comment: According to the definition you provided, it's not a nominal sentence.

Comment: It's a verb phrase. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Scratch the surface](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scratch+the+surface)*** is actually an idiomatic expression, you are probably referring to the figurative usage:

> 1. Lit. to scratch something just on the surface, not extending the mark below the finish into the wood, stone, marble, below. There is no serious damage done to the bench. You only scratched the surface.
> 2. Fig. to just begin to find out about something; to examine only the superficial aspects of something. The investigation of the governor's staff revealed some suspicious dealing. It is thought that the investigators have just scratched the surface. We don't know how bad the problem is. We've only scratched the surface.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.)

Comment: Yes, I do refer to the figurative usage. However, I'm not sure if "__ of the universe through science and technology" fits nicely with the "scratching the surface".

Comment: @rcx - what do you  mean by "fits nicely"?

Answer (score 1):

It just means to begin. As in agriculture. just scratching the surface does not make the earth ready for planting but it is the start. The surface does look changed dramatically, but it is not the end goal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).